# What does the dot mean after -rwxr-xr-x in the ls -l output?

Tags: linux

What is the meaning of the  dot '.' after last (the rightest one ) 'x' in the second line ?
This is the output of

> [igor@localhost ~]$ ls -l /usr/local/bin

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  113797 Aug 20 05:30 gpib
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   30283 Jul 16 22:48 ibtest
```

No, this is not the only dot in the output from 'ls -l'. There are many ... but NOT on every line.
(CentOS 6.4 32-bit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a look at `info ls What\ information`, it tells you

> Following the file mode bits is a single character that specifies 
>   whether an alternate access method such as an access control list 
>   applies to the file.  When the character following the file mode  bits
>   is a space, there is no alternate access method. When it is a
>   printing character, then there is such a method.
>
> GNU 'ls' uses a '.' character to indicate a file with an SELinux 
>   security context, but no other alternate access method.
>
> A file with any other combination of alternate access methods is 
>   marked with a '+' character.